# How to access a typedef of a template template class

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

When trying to compile the following code:

```
class Object
{
};

template <class OBJECT>
class Manager
{
public:
    typedef OBJECT Object_t;
};

template <class MANAGER>
class Container
{
    MANAGER::Object_t m_obj;
};

Container<Manager<Object> > container;
```

I get the following error:

prog.cpp:15: error: type ‘MANAGER’ is not derived from type ‘Container’

prog.cpp:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘m_obj’

Thanks

Comment: `typename` before `MANAGER::Object_t`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 4):

You need `typename` since the compiler does not know that `MANAGER::Object_t` refers to a type when it is parsing the template.

```
typename MANAGER::Object_t m_obj;
```

The first error message means the compiler is treating the scoped `MANAGER::` token as trying to access a base class member of `Container`. The second error message indicates the compiler didn't know that `m_obj` was supposed to be a data member, since it didn't recognize the token before it to be a type.